# Loop an entire column and place formual (advance excel)

Tags: excel

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>12345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saman</td>
    <td>99999</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>12345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jhonny</td>
    <td>88888</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Roshan</td>
    <td>77777</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rohit</td>
    <td>55555</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Roshan</td>
    <td>7777</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I need a table like that in **EXCEL SHEET**,

if I type same data in same column like in here If I type `john` so the `number` `12345` automatically place in there ,

I mean if the data `name` are repeated than the `number` field automatically fill .
so please suggest me the solution, how did I get result like that ?

Comment: Can you use a lookup table?

Comment: I don't know more about lookup table. Can I solve this problem by just placing some EXCEL formula , without using VBA script?

Comment: If i had to use VBA, so how can I solve this ? I mean the code of this solution ?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a lookup table.

You set your data up as an [Excel table](http://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html) (columns A&B). In the second column you enter a [VLOOKUP](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions02.html) formula e.g.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$G$7,2,FALSE)
```

Where `$F$2:$G$7` is the range (lookup table) holding the unique list of values to lookup. You could assign it as a named range and reference the [named range](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html).

As it is an Excel table the formula will autofill down the rows in the second column for every new name you add.

You will need to make sure the lookup list is complete (or specify text to return if name is not found in lookup table).

[image: Data]

Comment: Thank you so much , This is working for me,
really thank you, you should be proud of you.
And if I want the same with both
like - if I place number than get name and if I place name than get number,
so how can I did this ??

Comment: In this context it is one or the other as you would be overwriting the formula in one column in order to use a formula in the other e.g. if you used an INDEX/MATCH function to find the row to return the nname for a given  number you would have to overwrite the VLOOKUP formula in a particular cell with the number.

Comment: Though if you want to know how to get the Name from a number do =INDEX($F$2:$F$7,MATCH(B2,$G$2:$G$7)), you just can't have both without using a third helper column and things getting more complicated.

Comment: Thank you , Thank you so much .